# Handling selected item in a list with pagination on autoupdating the list in a react app ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, user-experience

I have a left section menu with a list that has pagination implemented. Now I am unsure as to how to handle a situation when the list updates and a new item is added to the top of the current list or multiple new items are added to the top of the list, how do I handle this scenario so that I am still on the selected item before the list was updated?

P.S.- Is it a good idea to recursively search for the order by changing pages when the selected item is not present in the updated list, or is there any better cost effective way to handle this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.